# Syncing code between local and remote computer

Tags: git, ssh, synchronization, githooks

I am trying to find a efficient way of syncing a project of mine that I am coding on my Mac and running on a Linux server which I login via SSH using a password. Also I need to login to a VPN to be able to connect to server. The project is about deep learning and that's why I am using the server. But the problem is I am having issues when it comes to share the folder between those systems. I have looked through internet for a solution and find some, however I am not sure whether if they would work.

Here is a timeline of my work to give better insight;

1. Develop some code on laptop and test it whether it works.
2. Send the code to the server.
3. Run it real this time for different parameters on server.
4. After execution save the models to server.
5. Send the models and other information that has been saved on the server to the laptop.

Previously, I was using git to those all things. However I have been facing merge conflicts occasionaly.

A solution with git that automatically pulls the code from github to server when I pushed a commit from laptop would work great for me, I think. However I do not know how to automatically send the models to my laptop with that way. Any help is appreciated.